# read data from Websocket

Tags: python, json, database, websocket, lorawan

I would like to read data from a websocket. The data was send by a LoRa node to a LORIOT service.

Here is the link of the webpage:

https://lora.service.itrm.de/apps/websocket.html?token=vgEAtgAAABRsb3JhLnNlcnZpY2UuaXRybS5kZfeagUUI80eb4B-eTvuwllM

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to web socket you may use websocket-client module https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client 
For quick installation via pip run: `pip install websocket-client`

To get the actual link to WebSocket you may use Developer Tools in any browser and get the link. For the link you've provided it's `wss://lora.service.itrm.de/app?token=vgEAtgAAABRsb3JhLnNlcnZpY2UuaXRybS5kZfeagUUI80eb4B-eTvuwllM`

Basically, you may construct the link for any token (I don't know how you've acquired this one :) ). Pattern is pretty obvious, just add token string to **wss://lora.service.itrm.de/app?token=**

I've tried connecting to WebSocket you've provided, it caused a bit of trouble with SSL certificate, so I've made a quick workaround:

```
import websocket
import ssl
ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
ws.connect(url='wss://lora.service.itrm.de/app?token=vgEAtgAAABRsb3JhLnNlcnZpY2UuaXRybS5kZfeagUUI80eb4B-eTvuwllM')
```

With usage of sslopt we basically disable SSL verification for our script.

Next you should define functions to handle messages, errors and connection closing, depending on what you're trying to achieve (refer to examples and documentation on GitHub link provided).

Comment: I used your code but I didn't receive the data                                                                                     import websocket
import ssl
ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
ws.connect(url='wss://lora.service.itrm.de/app?token=vgEAtgAAABRsb3JhLnNlcnZpY2UuaXRybS5kZfeagUUI80eb4B-eTvuwllM')

result =  ws.recv()
print("Receiving...")

print("Received '%s'" % result)
ws.close()

Comment: @AbdelmoumenNorrdine you were not supposed to receive any data. I've just provided the connection part, since you’ve just mentioned reading data without any details on what you're planning to do :). Please, refer to documentation on https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/master/README.rst